# MongoDB create replicaSet

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

ive created M0 Cluster Sandbox via Mongo Atlas. It is working pretty nice. But I want to use transactions with it. And I've read that to use transactions I need to have a replica set.

In the Atlas it seems like my DB have a replicaSet already (i didn't do anything). So how i can connect to that replica set?

[image]

My current connection link is `mongodb+srv://admin:password@de.xxx.mongodb.net/db?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MongoDB Atlas M0 Cluster is replica-set by default. You can connect to the cluster using the provided Connection URI.

Comment: There are some limitations when using the free M0 cluster; refer this: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/free-shared-limitations/

Comment: Do you want to connect using the mongodb shell, compass or an application?

Comment: @biorubenfs im connecting to my Node.JS application

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough with passing the connection string when you create your `MongoClient` object:

```js
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');

const uri = "your_string_connection";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { options-you-need });

client.connect(err => {
    const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
  
    // perform actions on the collection object
    client.close();
});
```

This code was copy-pasted from atlas cluster instructions to connect to the cluster: Connect your applications -> check `Include full driver code example`.